# search form php/sql multiple inputs

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, search

i've a problem with a search form. It works only if I use all the 4 fields, but if a leave a field empty the while loop echoes out all the table's records.

Can someone please help me?

This is my php code for the search function

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['cerca'])){


    $cerca_tt = $_POST['tt_carrier'];
    $cerca_risorsa = $_POST['risorsa_cerca'];
    $cerca_team = $_POST['team_cerca'];
    $cerca_linea = $_POST['linea_cerca'];


    $sql_cerca = "SELECT * FROM normal WHERE 
                tt LIKE '%".$cerca_tt."%'
                OR risorsa LIKE '%".$cerca_risorsa."%' 
                OR team LIKE '%".$cerca_team."%' 
                OR linea LIKE '%".$cerca_linea."%'";

        if($sql_cerca) {

            $trovati = mysql_query($sql_cerca); ?>
```

Comment: where is the while loop?

Comment: this `if($sql_cerca) {` is redundant. Its just a string , you know

Comment: You should have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) and at [extract function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.extract.php)

Comment: Solved, i used 4 input field in the upper code, now i search just with 1 field all the values that i need.

Answer (score 0):

if the POST is blank then the variable is blank thus everything will match  like '%%'

for example if $cerca_tt is blank.  your query would be

```
   "SELECT * FROM normal WHERE tt like '%%'"
```

that matches everything.

create the query based on the POST response.

```
 $sel = "SELECT * from normal";
```

//You will need to deal with the WHERE part of the query.

```
 if (!empty($cerca_tt)){
     $sel .= " OR tt like '%".$cerca_tt."'";
 }
```

etc....///

Comment: Solved, i used 4 input field in the upper code, now i search just with 1 field all the values that i need.

Answer (score 0):

If you only provide one search parameter and the rest are empty strings, which you wrap with %, you are effectively searching everything. You need to build up your query. For example (simple):

```
$sqlParts = [];

if(isset($_POST['tt_carrier'])) {
    $sqlParts[] = "tt LIKE '%".$cerca_tt."%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['risorsa_cerca'])) {
    $sqlParts[] = "risorsa LIKE '%".$cerca_risorsa."%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['team_cerca'])) {
    $sqlParts[] = "team LIKE '%".$cerca_team."%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['team_cerca'])) {
    $sqlParts[] = "linea LIKE '%".$linea_cerca."%'";
}

if(!empty($sqlParts)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM normal WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $sqlParts);
}
```

Comment: Solved, i used 4 input field in the upper code, now i search just with 1 field all the values that i need.